sem_wait() triggers a SIGBUS exception
I have a C++ Linux commandline application, which does a bunch of things and then closes by itself. I am blocking the main thread using a semaphore and when the background thread completes its activity, it unlocks the semaphore, releasing the main thread, which returns from int main().
// Static definition of the semaphore object. This semaphore object is 
// declared as a static array of 32 bytes in class A
uint8_t  A::semaphore[sizeof(sem_t)];
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

// In int main()
if(sem_init ((sem_t *) A::semaphore, 0, 0)) {
    // failed to initialize semaphore
}

printf("semaphore = %p\n", A::semaphore);  // Prints 0x129ba01

// Create another thread(s) to execute work

// Main thread gets blocked here... until thread(s) complete their work.
sem_wait ((sem_t *) A::semaphore);

// Once main thread gets unblocked, return from int main() with return value

I've also attached my own exception handler using sigaction. It turns out that, when main thread reaches sem_wait, my exception handler gets invoked with the signal number value of 7, which is a SIGBUS exception. I've also printed additional details using siginfo_t object passed to the exception handler.
// Exception handler belonging to Class B
void B::handleException(int32_t signum, siginfo_t * info, void * context) noexcept
{
    printf("signo = %d\n", info->si_signo); // Prints 7
    printf("errno = %d\n", info->si_errno);
    printf("code = %d\n", info->si_code);
    printf("si_addr = %p\n", info->si_addr); // Prints 0x129ba01


    ....
}

As shown above, the caught exception is SIGBUS and the si_addr property of siginfo - which points to the memory location of the fault, prints the address of the semaphore. Then, the signal documentation states the following for SIGBUS:

For example, an invalid memory access that causes delivery of SIGSEGV on one CPU architecture may cause delivery of SIGBUS on another architecture, or vice versa.

I think what I'm really getting is a SIGSEGV exception... and there is some memory access violation... but I'm not able to find it.
What am I missing here?
Note: SIGBUS gets thrown only on Linux arm64. My app works fine on Linux x64.

Your semaphore is not shared between threads in the process or between processes. Why aren't you using a std::mutex instead?

Why are you using an array instead of a proper sem_t object directly? Why are you using the unsafe C function printf in a C++ program?

You don't even show threads. That said since C++11, there are std::thread, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock/std::unique_lock, std::barrier, std::binary_sempahore, std::counting_semaphore... more than enough building blocks to write portable/debugable and readable code. That due to RAII behavior of locks is more likely not to deadlock in exception sitatutions, so use those

@Someprogrammerdude, This code is an example... a small representation of a bigger context. printf is not used in the main program.

@TedLyngmo, According to sem_init documentation, when 0 as the second parameter, it is shared b/w threads of a process, as long as its present in some address visible to all threads.  Can you elaborate your statement?

@NightFuryLxD You are correct. I read it wrong. Still, why not simply use a std::mutex?

@TedLyngmo std::mutex may be simpler and safer to use, but I want this app to run only on linux. Using the OS's artefact is faster than using C++'s artefact.

@NightFuryLxD Why do you think its faster to use semaphores than std::mutex? std::mutex is just a wrapper around pthread_mutex (same size, so no extra member variables) and should be pretty efficient.

@TedLyngmo I'm not sure about mutex, but my understanding was, using an OS artefact is faster than a wrapper (C++ std libs). This is followed in the project I'm part of... thus I've demonstrated like this.  As you said, it may not be that inefficient.

@NightFuryLxD I recommend that you don't make such assumptions. The wrapper std::mutex provides member functions that call the pthread_mutex_* functions and makes it usable with other standard types, such as std::lock_guard etc. That's it. When compiled, there will nothing left of the wrapper. Use the standard types unless you need some platform specific functionality or that you have proved that the standard implementation is slower than the native one.

You're stuffing your sem_t into a byte array, which has no alignment requirements, but sem_t almost certainly does.  So when you go to actually use it, you get an error from accessing unaligned memory.
You should be using a sem_t if you want a sem_t.  Or just use the threading and IPC primitives that have been in C++ for a while now.

Can you help me understand why memory alignment is a problem in this context?

when accessing N bytes, the address of the location should be a multiple of N. If its not, then its unaligned memory access. In this scenario, the byte array may be aligned, but when intepreting it as a sem_t type, one of its internal members may become unaligned and compiler cannot help here, since this is runtime. Is this right?

@NightFuryLxD The bytes in the array should have a start address that is aligned like sem_t wants it, for example alignof(sem_t) uint8_t semaphore[sizeof(sem_t)]; - But, why make it an array of uint8_ts?!

@TedLyngmo, It should be alignas(sem_t) right?

@NightFuryLxD Yes, alignas, my bad - but still, don't do that. Use the type created for this instead and you don't have to bother with aligning a uint8_t buffer.
